# Shell Script : Printing two lines as different lines but in the same cell in a csv file

Tags: shell, unix

I have to print two lines as two different lines in a csv file, but in the same cell using shell scripting. Could anyone help me out in achieving the same..

I have two lines stored in separate variables. How to echo or print them to a csv file so both lines come in a single cell?

I'm able to get the two different lines in csv files but not in the same cell..

I'm trying to do :

```
var1="abc"
var2="zyz"

eval echo -e '"${var1}" \n"${var2}"' > outputfile.csv
```

I want the output in the csv file as:

```
abc
xyz
```

but in the same cell...

Comment: If I correctly understand your problem, then you're trying to do this:
`line1=lorem`
`line2=ipsum`
`file.csv -> lorem,ipsum`
Provide some sample what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include a newline in a single cell, you need to double quote it so the output of the command is

```
"abc
zyz"
```

You can do it with *echo* with some escaping this way

```
echo -e \""$var1"\\n"$var2"\"
```

Perhaps more readable (and more portable) is using *printf*

```
printf '"%s\n%s"' "$var1" "$var2"
```